# ld: cannot find .... Error when compiling CAMB in a cluster (ifort compiler)

Tags: linux, centos, cluster-computing, ld, library-path

I'm trying to install the program CAMB in a cluster environment. I'm using the ifort compiler.

Whenever I type `make` I get this error:

`ld: cannot find -lm 
 ld: cannot find -lstdc++ 
 ld: cannot find -lpthread
 ld: cannot find -lc
 ld: cannot find -ldl
 ld: cannot find -lc
 make: *** [camb] Error 1`

I think there must be an issue concerning my ld library path, but I don't know how to fix it (actually since I don't have sudo privileges I don't know if it's fixable at all).

Currently in my .bashrc file I have:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64
```

Any help at all will be much appreciated...

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer `cat /etc/*release` returns "CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)"

Answer (score 0):

The Fortran compiler needs the C and C++ runtime libraries for linking programs.  The official way of installing them on CentoS is to run

```
# yum install gcc gcc-c++
```

as root.  This will indirectly provide all the required development packages.

Comment: I can't because as I said I don't have root privileges in the cluster, I'm just a user....

Comment: It looks like you are not expected to consume precious resources on the cluster by compiling software there. There should be someone who can provide you with a matching development environment.